# Confusion - Delete node from position K in Linked List (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, logic

I'm studying data structures in Javascript to prep for interviews and am a bit stumped by a return value in the solution. Details below.

**The Problem**
(Reference Link): https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/delete-a-node-from-a-linked-list/problem

Delete the node at a given position in a linked list and return a reference to the head node. The head is at position 0. The list may be empty after you delete the node. In that case, return a null value.

**Boilerplate:**

```
const SinglyLinkedListNode = class {
    constructor(nodeData) {
        this.data = nodeData;
        this.next = null;
    }
};

const SinglyLinkedList = class {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    insertNode(nodeData) {
        const node = new SinglyLinkedListNode(nodeData);

        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            this.tail.next = node;
        }

        this.tail = node;
    }
};

function printSinglyLinkedList(node, sep, ws) {
    while (node != null) {
        ws.write(String(node.data));

        node = node.next;

        if (node != null) {
            ws.write(sep);
        }
    }
}
```

**And the functional answer:**

```
/*
 * Complete the 'deleteNode' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. INTEGER_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST llist
 *  2. INTEGER position
 */


/*
 * For your reference:
 *
 * SinglyLinkedListNode {
 *     int data;
 *     SinglyLinkedListNode next;
 * }
 *
 */

function deleteNode(llist, position) {
    
    let head = llist
    let currentNode = head
    let count = 1
    
    if (head === null) return;
    if (position === 0){ 
        head = head.next
        return head
  
    if (currentNode === null || currentNode.next === null) return;
    while (count < position){
        count++
        currentNode = currentNode.next   
    }
    currentNode.next = currentNode.next.next
    return head
    }
```

This function appears to pass all tests provided.

**My question is:** Why does returning 'head' give me the correct answer? It does not appear that head is being altered in the function. Returning llist also gives a correct answer as well.

I've tried returning currentNode but obviously that provides the values from currentNode on.

Comment: `head` is altered when `position` is zero.

Comment: How does llist also work as a return value?

Comment: It won't when `position` is zero!

Comment: I really appreciate the response. P.S. Do you know of any good resources of visualizing or stepping through this function? I think there's something missing in my understanding of the logic.

Comment: I'm old so I use `console.log()` :)

Comment: The main thing is this: `head` either *does* change (when deleting the first node), or it *doesn't* change. Either way, returning `head` leaves the caller with the correct reference: the start of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does returning 'head' give me the correct answer?

Because `head` is a reference to a node. It is only because that node itself also has a reference to a next node, and that next node might also have a reference to a next node, that this `head` reference *implies* a linked list. Even though the node that `head` references might remain the same node, somewhere along that chain of `next` references, there might be a change (and will be), and so *implicitly* the `head` reference leads to a linked list that is no longer the same.

> It does not appear that head is being altered in the function.

Unless it is the head node itself that needs to be removed, this is a true statement. That is because `head` only references the first node. So if the first node has to stay in the linked list, `head` does not need to change. What will change is a `next` reference somewhere along the way.

> Returning `llist` also gives a correct answer as well.

Yes, the introduction of the variable `head` is actually overkill. We can solve this without that extra variable and just use `llist` where this code uses `head`.

It may help to visualise this.

Let's say we have a linked list with four nodes (with values 1, 2, 3 and 4) and `position` is 2. Then when the code execution arrives at the `while` statement, we have this state:

```
llist
head  currentNode
  ↓      ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next:None │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

As `position` is 2, the purpose of this code is to remove the node with value 3 from this list.

The `while` loop will make one iteration in this case, so that `currentNode` will reference the *predecessor* of the node that needs to be removed:

```
llist
head             currentNode
  ↓                ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next:None │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

The first statement after the while loop performs a "redirection" of the `next` reference that is stored in that predecessor node:

```
llist
head             currentNode
  ↓                ↓           ┌────────────────┐
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │ │  │ value: 3  │ └> │ value: 4  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ──────┘  │ next: ───────> │ next:None │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Note that there is nothing anymore that references the node with value 3. It has become unreachable to any JavaScript code. The garbage collector can free its memory, so the above is no different from this:

```
llist
head             currentNode
  ↓                ↓           
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 4  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next:None │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

In all this process, `head` did not change. The change is reflected in one of the nodes that is in the chain of `next` references, and so we could say the linked list was *mutated*.

I hope this clarifies how it works.

Comment: This definitely clears things up for me. Likely the best answer I've had to a question on here. Thanks a ton!